# Let $K/F$ be an arbitrary extension and $a \in K$.Then is there a $\sigma \in Gal(K/F)$ such that $\sigma(a) = b$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K/F$ be an arbitrary extension and $a \in K$. If $b$ is any root of $min(F,a)$ in $K$, then is there a $\sigma \in Gal(K/F)$ such that $\sigma(a) = b$ ?

That is here I want to know that the statement we know is true if $K/F$ is normal is it still true if we remove normality? If not then give me a counter example and come up with a minimal condition for which this will be true.

Comment: If $K/F$ is not normal, what is $Gal(K/F)$?

Comment: it's still the automorphisms of $K$ that fix $F$. If it's not normal then you  have $|Gal(K/F)| < [K : F]$.

Comment: Just to make sure: I guess you know case where $K/F$ is finite (then such a $\sigma$ easily exists)? And you are asking mainly about the infinite case?

Comment: What is $\min(F,a)$ when $a$ is transcendental?

Comment: For $K/F$ normal I know the proof of both finite and infinite cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F = \mathbb{Q}, K = F(2^{1/4}), a = \sqrt{2}, b = -\sqrt{2}$. Then all the conditions are satisfied, but if $\sigma \in Gal(K/F)$, then
$$
\sigma(2^{1/4}) = \pm 2^{1/4} \Rightarrow \sigma(a) = a
$$
Hence, there is no $\sigma \in Gal(K/F)$ such that $\sigma(a) = b$.

I am not sure what the minimal condition is, although I suspect normality is it.

Comment: Very nice. I wracked my brain over this, going down one false path after another.